# Issue returning the array value from a function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, image

I have a problem returning an array from a class in c++. I created a dummy images, and I wanted to return the images so that I can use in another class. But somehow it doesnt work as expected.

Declaration:

```
public:
    void Create_Marvin();                    //Create dummy marvin image
    double* Get_Data();                      //Get the dummy marvin image

private:
    int Color = 2;                           //Example color value
    int Width = 3;                           //Example width value
    int Height = 2;                          //Example height value
    double* Marvin_Image[2][2][3];           //Marvin image with [c][h][w] array orders
    double Marvin_Test_Data[12];
```

Function Implementation:

```
void Create_Dummy_Marvin_Image::Create_Marvin()
{
    int x = 0; //Random value initialisation
    for (int c = 0; c < Color; ++c)                  //Iterating through color values
    {
        for (int h = 0; h < Height; ++h)             //Iterating through height of the image
        {
            for (int w = 0; w < Width; ++w)          //Iterating through width of the image
            {
                x = ++x;                           //Incrementing the value of x
                Marvin_Image[c][h][w] = (double *)x; //Setting the value in the arrays to form marvin image with random values
                //cout << "Marvin image :" << int(Marvin_Image[c][h][w]) << "\n"; //Checking the values 
                Marvin_Test_Data[c*h*w] = Marvin_Image[c][h][w];
                cout << "\n Marvin image :" << int(Marvin_Test_Data[c*h*w]);

            }
        }
    }

}

//Get the dummy marvin image
double* Create_Dummy_Marvin_Image::Get_Data()
{
    //return Marvin_Image[Color][Height][Width]; //Returning the marvin image ;
    return Marvin_Test_Data;

}
```

When I print the data from the main function, The Create_Marvin(), correctly prints the data. But the returned value doesn't print it as required.

Main():

```
    double* Dummy_Single_Dim_Image[12]; //Single dimensional image with little more array data to avoid unprecidented results
Dummy_Image.Create_Marvin();
    Dummy_Single_Dim_Image[12] = Dummy_Image.Get_Data(); //Get the marvin image as three dimensional matrix with [c][h][w]
```

The above line is where the problem comes if I set the Dummy_Single_Dim_Image[12]; Then the console produces

```
 Final matlab output :2010112908
 Final matlab output :1993390502
 Final matlab output :0
 Final matlab output :6488492
 Final matlab output :6488064
 Final matlab output :6029344
 Final matlab output :1
 Final matlab output :6488400
 Final matlab output :19499094
 Final matlab output :-2
 Final matlab output :6488260
 Final matlab output :16777219
```

But if I set the array as Dummy_Single_Dim_Image[14]; It produces like

```
 Final matlab output :3
 Final matlab output :2
 Final matlab output :1
 Final matlab output :2
 Final matlab output :3
 Final matlab output :4
 Final matlab output :5
 Final matlab output :6
 Final matlab output :7
 Final matlab output :8
 Final matlab output :9
 Final matlab output :0
```

Neither is my required output as it should just have the values from 1 to 12

Made the following changes

```
double Marvin_Image[2][2][3];           //Marvin image with [c][h][w] array orders
double Marvin_Test_Data[12];

double* Create_Dummy_Marvin_Image::Get_Data()
{
    //return Marvin_Image[Color][Height][Width]; //Returning the marvin image ;
    return Marvin_Test_Data;

}
```

But it again produces some weird output when I print it in the main function like

```
    double* Dummy_Single_Dim_Image; //Single dimensional image with little more array data to avoid unprecidented results
Dummy_Image.Create_Marvin();
    Dummy_Single_Dim_Image  = Dummy_Image.Get_Data(); //Get the marvin image 
for (int c = 0; c < 2; ++c)                  //Iterating through color values
    {
        for (int h = 0; h < 2; ++h)             //Iterating through height of the image
        {
            for (int w = 0; w < 3; ++w)          //Iterating through width of the image
            {
                cout << "\n Final matlab output :" << int(Dummy_Single_Dim_Image[c*h*w]);
            }
        }
    }
```

My output:

```
 Final matlab output :10
 Final matlab output :10
 Final matlab output :10
 Final matlab output :10
 Final matlab output :10
 Final matlab output :10
 Final matlab output :10
 Final matlab output :10
 Final matlab output :10
 Final matlab output :10
 Final matlab output :11
 Final matlab output :12
```

This prints the correct order from the array in the main function. I don't understand why !!!

```
for (int i = -12; i < 0; ++i)
{
    cout << "\n Final matlab output :" << int(Dummy_Single_Dim_Image[i]);
}
```

Comment: Try `return Marvin_Test_Data;` instead of `return Marvin_Test_Data[12];`

Comment: Why arrays of pointers? and not array to `double`s

Comment: C++ array starts with index 0. Marvin_Test_Data[12] is out of the boundary.

Comment: Use `std::array` (or `std::vector`) which has a more intuitive interface.

Comment: This is unneccessary by the way `x = ++x;`. You can just say `++x;` it will increment in place.

Comment: Start with *not* having images made up of pointers, which makes no sense at all. (Your code is full of strangeness (`x = ++x;`, `(double *)x`) which suggests that you could spend some time reviewing the basics in your fine C++ book.)

Comment: @wolfPack88 I tried it but it again creates an error, which I have posted in the below comment...

Comment: @molbdnilo I did the following, and changed a few other yet I am stuck with some issues

Comment: @user3703782 First you figure out what's wrong, then you change things. You won't stumble upon a solution. Start with calculating `c*h*w` for each round in your loops, by hand.

Comment: @molbdnilo I have updated my query. I get the right order when I iterate from -12 to 0, rather than the other way. Its so confusing....

Comment: @user3703782 Those indexes aren't even inside the array, so it's just coincidence. Again: Check what `c*w*h` is in your loops.

Comment: @molbdnilo I figured out, c*w*h are 1,2,3,2,4,6,2,4,6,4,8,12.I tried accessing these elements individually but the data are not what it should supposed to contain. I couldn't understand why...

Comment: @user3703782 If you can get `1` from `0 * 0 * 0`, you need to learn basic arithmetic before you write any more code.

Answer (score 0):

First off:

```
return Marvin_Test_Data[12];
```

is returning something that doesn't exist.  `Marvin_Test_Data` is an array of 12 `double *` elements.  Arrays in C/C++ start at 0, so the last element is `Marvin_Test_Data[11]` but it's unlikely that this was you intented.  You probable wanted and array of `double` (*not* pointers to `double`) and you wanted to return a pointer to the start of that `double` array, something more like:

```
double Marvin_Test_Data[12];

double* Create_Dummy_Marvin_Image::Get_Data() {
    return Marvin_Test_Data;
}
```

to return a pointer to your data.

Comment: @PaulEvens  I get the following as my output : `Final matlab output :10
 Final matlab output :10
 Final matlab output :10
 Final matlab output :10
 Final matlab output :10
 Final matlab output :10
 Final matlab output :10
 Final matlab output :10
 Final matlab output :10
 Final matlab output :10
 Final matlab output :11
 Final matlab output :12 `